# DIV Scroll down to bottom Script Error JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recieve an Error from this function

```
function scrolldown() {
$("#chatArea").scrollTop($("#chatArea")[0].scrollHeight);
}
```

> Fehler: TypeError: $(...)[0] is undefined

this script is called in a ajax query to update an Chatbox to scroll to the bottom

```
function refreshChat()
{       
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "ajax/sb.php",
           success: function(msg){
                $("#chatArea").html(msg);
                scrolldown();
           }
      });
}
```

Updates every 5 seconds

```
window.setInterval("refreshChat()",5000);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What you'r trying to do with this $("#chatArea")[0]?? The correct is $("#chatArea").find(0);

Comment: @Guerra `$("#chatArea")[0]` will return the DOM element instead of the jQuery object.

Comment: @Guerra you are wrong, his solution is correct. What does `console.log($("#chatArea").size())` output?

Comment: Maybe you have typo in `#chatArea` are you sure you have <div id="chatArea">...</div> in html?

Comment: Just a side note you don't need to add a [0] since you are selecting an id. Assuming you aren't duplicating your ids that is.

Comment: @PatsyIssa if he wants to get the native DOM element from the selector, he does need the `[0]`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Missed the scrollHeight my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work

```
function scrolldown() {
    $("#chatArea").scrollTop(document.getElementById('chatArea').scrollHeight);
}
```

Taking away the fact that using `$("#chatArea")[0]` will return the dom element with jQuery. But for whatever reason it seems to be returning an error.

**Edit**

My answer has fixed the original issue but you have updated with:

```
 TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

Which basically means that the element is not found. In short when the function runs `$("#chatArea")` is not in the DOM. It does not exist. Please make sure `$("#chatArea")` is available when the function is run.

Comment: same problems as before

Comment: i thought it work but as i looked later for it later Zeitstempel: 01.10.2013 18:42:29
Fehler: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function scrolldown() {
    $("#chatArea").scrollTop($("#chatArea").get(0).scrollHeight);
}
```

Comment: same Problem

>Fehler: TypeError: $(...).get(...) is undefined